# why debian repository does not contain lokkit?

Tags: debian, rhel, iptables

I was using lokkit in redhat, and I want to use it in debian, but it seems that debian doesn't contain it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gnome-lokkit and lokkit were removed from Debian some time ago. See 
[RM: gnome-lokkit -- RoQA; buggy, dead upstream, old gnome-libs, alternatives exist](http://bugs.debian.org/508396). As stated there, the reasons given were:

> - Buggy.
> - Dead upstream.
> - Depends on gnome-libs which is scheduled for removal.
> - Alternatives exist

See also the thread [Suggestion for "fixing" RC bugs (binNMU + removal(s))](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.release/20127/) on debian-release.